# Merge two lines of list comprehensions into one

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples, like this:

```
loft = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
odd = [1, 3, 5]
even = [2, 4, 6]
```

I can achieve this like this:

```
odd = [x[0] for x in loft]
even = [x[1] for x in loft]
```

But I need to do it in one line. I tried this:

```
odd, even = [x[0], x[1] for x in loft]
```

But gives me this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    odd, even = [x[0], x[1] for x in loft]
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it possible to do it in one line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use unpacking with `zip`:

```
loft = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
odd, even = zip(*loft)
```

Output:

```
(1, 3, 5)
(2, 4, 6)
```

If you wish the results to be `list`s, rather than `tuple`s, you can use `map`:

```
loft = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
odd, even = map(list, zip(*loft))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 6]
```